# Convert ISO-8859-1 encoding bytes to UTF-8

Tags: javascript, character-encoding

I have a file of which the binary looks like: 8950 4e47 0d0a 1a0a 0000 000d 4948 4452.

I want to decode these bytes into a string by using ISO-8859-1, for exmaple, "50" is "P", "4E" is "N" and 47 is "G".

However, I cannot do that in JavaScript because the decode method "fromCharCode()" is Unicode by default.

What I can think of is to convert the binary itself to UTF-8 first. For example, "50" in ISO-8859-1 represents the same value "P" in UTF-8, so "50" remains "50", but "89" in ISO-8859-1 represents nothing, I don't know how to choose a UTF-8 encoding to replace it.

Can anyone provide some help on this conversion function?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`TextDecoder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder) class. If your browser doesn't [support it](https://caniuse.com/#feat=textencoder), you can use [this polyfill](https://github.com/inexorabletash/text-encoding).

```js
let bytes = new Uint8Array([0x89, 0x50, 0x4e, 0x47, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x1a, 0x0a, 
                            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0d, 0x49, 0x48, 0x44, 0x52]);
let decoder = new TextDecoder('iso-8859-1');
console.log(decoder.decode(bytes));
```

Comment: I'm interested in this. what I don't understand is this part: [0x89, 0x50, 0x4e, 0x47, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x1a, 0x0a, 
                            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0d, 0x49, 0x48, 0x44, 0x52] should I replace this by my data ?

Comment: @Eagle1 Yes. Those are the raw binary bytes which need to be parsed as ISO-8859-1.